# How secure are ASP.net security cookies

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies

My understanding is that ASP generates a cookie to authenticate a session. However, if that cookie is sent back and forth over a non https channel, can't I spoof it simply by spoofing the cookie? Can the cookie be locked to a particular IP or other machine fingerprint?

Comment: If the cookie locked together with some other parameter, then all parameters together must be go back and front. So if some one can read the cookie can read and the rest parameters as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions in ASP.NET aren't authenticated - authentication is entirely separate. By taking a session cookie and recreating it yes you can hijack the session, and if you lift an authentication cookie then you can authenticate as a user (which is why, by default, authentication cookies expire) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

The security note is quite clear;

> SessionID values are sent in clear text, whether as a cookie or as
>   part of the URL. A malicious user could get access to the session of
>   another user by obtaining the SessionID value and including it in
>   requests to the server. If you are storing sensitive information in
>   session state, it is recommended that you use SSL to encrypt any
>   communication between the browser and server that includes the
>   SessionID value.

Answer (score 1):

At my last job we worked around this by tracking the user's session ID (we appended a guid to the URL as a query string, there are other ways) in a database where we would also store the ip address which made the request.  For all subsequent requests (anything with a session ID, a requirement to get any sensitive information) we simply check the session ID and the ip making the request against the values stored when we authenticated and set up the session.  Request.UserHostAddress is a little harder to spoof.  There is some overhead, but it is way more secure than cookies.

Comment: Just curious - Did you have a mechanism for alerting if this check failed, and if so, did it ever happen live in production?

Comment: All of our apps had some sort of logging.  I don't recall it happening, but, it was rampant in production before we made that change.  Our problem was not hackers, it was url sharers.  Corporate employees would send links to agents, not realizing that the link, with its session ID gave access to data with it.  They would pick one agent as an example and expose that agent's data to everyone they shared the link with.  This mechanism shut that practice down cold.  They would just be denied access and, if I recall correctly, redirected to a login page.

Comment: Very interesting thank you. I implemented something very similar as an intrusion breaker and in 4 years never had it trip a single time.